# Pentaho: Switch -> Insert row into two tables

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a merge-diff, if the rows are "changed", I need to insert that into two different rows.

How can I direct "changed" CASE to two different tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up duplicating the rows to TWO switch-case, one for each table.

It does not look elegant, not sure if there is a maintainable/better/efficient way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the switch step is thought to have only one hop out for each condition, and once a condition is met, it doesn't evaluate the rest of the conditions, so if you need to stream the rows for one of the conditions to two separate steps, in this case the Dummy step would be my choice too, to allow afterwards two or more hops with a copy row to next step.